# CSS transparant top right triangle border

Tags: css

I have a block(div) with a lineair gradient.
Is it possible to make the top right corner to cut out a triangle?

You have border-radius 5px for instance to make a block with round corners. But is it possible to have a transparant top right corner of 40px?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Where's that div you have? Share some code

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Please elaborate and provide code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-top-right-radius&preval=100px

Only not rounded but a sharp corner like a triangle. (Straight line)

```
<div class="top-block">content</div>

.top-block {
    background: lineair-gradient(from top to right, red, blue);
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect with ::after / :: before elements like this.

```
.yourelement{
    position:relative; // Required.
}
.yourelement::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 40px solid #fff; // YOUR BG COLOR
    top: 0px;
    right:0px
}
```

You can base the px sizes on the size of your element as you please, also adjust the colors etc.

this essentially places a triangle over your corner to make it appear cut.